# Buffer filling last empty spaces in char array with unwanted data

Tags: c++

```
FILE* file_;
        char buffer[5];
                file_ = fopen("Data.txt", "a+");
        while (!feof(file_)) 
        {
            fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, file_);
            cout << buffer<<" ";
            BM(buffer, pat);
        }
```

Data.txt="ABCC1ABCC2XXX"

Output:

ABCC1m

ABCC2m

XXX**C2**m

How can I make buffer stop before it starts generating chars from previous buffer?(bolded font part)

Wanted output:

ABCC1

ABCC2

XXX

Comment: Are you randomizing your indentation? Anyway, the problem is you're missing the C string's null terminator. I'll see if I can find a good duplicate ... but since you tagged C++, you could actually use `std::string` and `std::ifstream` and save yourself a lot of effort.

Comment: Change `sizeof(buffer)` to `sizeof(buffer) - 1`, in order to avoid overriding the null character.

Comment: @goodvibration You need to *put* a null character in there.  There isn't one by default.

Comment: @MartinBonner: I haven't worked with `fread` in a while, so I've figured out of the back of my memory that it adds the null character after the amount of characters requested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two problems.  Firstly you are not null-terminating `buffer` at all, (which is why you are getting the `m` output.  Secondly, you are not null-terminating `buffer` in the right place when there is a short read.

`fread` will tell you how many characters it has read, and you need to put the `'\0'` there.  **Edit**  That previous description is not accurate.  It tells you how many *objects* it has read, each of size arg2, and you read upto arg3 of them.  You need to change the arguments to `fread` so that you are reading single characters, and as many of them as there room in the buffer.  So:

```
        FILE* file_;
        char buffer[5+1];
                file_ = fopen("Data.txt", "a+");
        while (!feof(file_)) 
        {
            const size_t nchars = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer)-1, file_);
            buffer[nchars] = '\0';
            cout << buffer<<" ";
            BM(buffer, pat);
        }
```

Pedantic note:  The second argument to `fread` could also be written as `sizeof(buffer[0])` if buffer is of something other than `char`/`signed char`/`unsigned char` - but those three are *defined* to have a sizeof 1.

Comment: `nchars` should be `size_t`, shouldn't it?

Comment: What's `i` by the way?

Comment: @Steve Good point - and fread doesn't return -1 on error (so I've removed that).

Comment: @goodvibration The variable now known as `nchars`.  I initially called it `i` (local variable, only valid for a small scope, don't need to think of a good name), then realized `nchars` would be a better name - but didn't change the uses!

Comment: You also checked if it was smaller than 0, which doesn't make much sense either if you intended for it to be the value returned from `fread` as you've just explained (since this function never returns a value smaller than 0).

Comment: My output after using @MartinBonner code is A /n A /n NULL, so it reads only every sixth character?

Answer (score 4):

OK, I can't find a decent duplicate - maybe someone else will.

The line

```
fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, file_);
```

*potentially* fills your buffer completely. You need to keep the return value to know how many bytes were actually written, but assuming your file contained at least five bytes, all five bytes of your `buffer` array are now initialized.

However, to print `buffer` as a regular C string, it needs a sixth byte, containing the null terminator.

For example, the C string `"12345"` is actually represented as the char array `{'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', 0}`.

You don't have room for a terminator in your buffer, and don't write one, so you can't treat it as a simple C string.

Your options are:

1. add a terminator manually, as in Martin Bonner's answer
2. don't add a terminator, but track the size - you can use the C++17

   ```
   std::string_view bufstr(buffer, nchars);
   ```

   to keep the pointer and size together (and you can print this normally)
3. stop using the old C I/O library entirely. The C++ I/O library admittedly doesn't have a much better way to read groups of five characters, but reading whole lines, for example, is much easier to do correctly.

Comment: I actually think this is a much better answer than mine.  +1

Comment: Thanks! Giving the OP the proximate solution quickly is always worthwhile too, though, and it's often more digestible.